# JavaScript: Array of Objects confusion

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist, javascript-objects

I understand an array of objects to be an array with objects in it and when it is logged to the console, it looks like the below.  I can tell that the `const iceCreams = [{type:'cup', flavor:'chocoloate'},{type:'cone', flavor:'vanilla'},{type:'cup', flavor:'strawberry'},{type:'conse', flavor:'mint'}]`

[image]

I was recently on a project and so something similar but instead of the index (0,1,2, etc.), there were a combination of numbers and letters which represented the id.  It looked something like this in the console.

[image]

Is this still an array of objects?  If so, why is the index not a number?  How is this represented in JavaScript code?

Comment: Please post code, logs and error messages as text. No, that's an object containing objects.

Comment: Array keys are numeric; Object keys can be alpha-numeric.

Comment: `{uyhbvf3er: {initialDate: ...}}`, but obviously dynamically populated, e.g. `result[someId] = someObject'`.

Comment: you can read about this here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: More at [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From the information provided in the question, this seems like a collection of Objects. This could be a bit deceiving when you first look at it. But it is not an array it is a collection of Objects where the key is a string (or number or both combined) and the value is also an object.

Please go through the following example I created and you may see something similar printed as in the picture.

[image]

Make sure to copy the code into the browser console and run it or better if you could create a code snippet in the browser source section so you could clearly inspect it. PLEASE NOTE Running this code in StackOverflow itself looks  different

```js
let demoObject =  { "abc":
    {
        "ADMISSION_ID" : 1632881,
        "ADDITIONAL_DATA" : null,
        "CREATED_BY" : "7348500",
        "CREATED_DATE" : "2022-09-29T03:27:06Z",
        "HOSPITAL" : 105,
        "HOSPITAL_GROUP_ID" : 58,
        "HOSPITAL_ID" : 105,
        "IS_ACTIVE" : null,
        "IS_DELETED" : 0,
        "LOCATION" : null,
        "MODIFIED_BY" : "1",
        "MODIFIED_DATE" : "2022-10-02T09:35:59Z",
        "ROW_VERSION" : 4,
        "TENANT_ID" : 58,
        "ADMISSION_NUMBER" : "A20229291626839",
        "ADMISSION_REASON" : "NON_SURGICAL",
        "ADMISSION_REQUEST_NO" : 1649632,
        "ADMISSION_STATUS" : "DISCHARGED",
        "ADMISSION_TYPE" : "Routine",
        "ADMITTED_BY_USER_ID" : null,
        "ADMITTED_BY_USER_NAME" : "Abdullah Ali Mohammed MANSOUR",
        "ADMITTED_DATE" : "2022-09-29T03:27:06Z",
        "ADMITTING_DOCTOR_ID" : 7245,
        "ADMITTING_DOCTOR_NAME" : "وليد نقر",
        "APPOINTMENT_ID" : null,
        "AUTOMATIC_CONSENT_TAKEN" : 0,
        "BED_CODE" : "ER-OBS F",
        "BED_LOCATION" : "Cluster S2 \/ Damad General Hospital \/ Damad General Hospital \/ Ground Floor \/ ER  \/ ER-OBS F",
        "BED_NO" : 3376,
        "BED_RESERVATION_ID" : 1031741,
        "CLINIC_GROUP_ID" : null,
        "CLINIC_ID" : 35376,
        "CLINIC_NAME" : "تخصص العيون فرز",
        "COMPANION_ID" : null,
        "COMPANION_NAME" : null,
        "COMPANY_APPROVAL_NO" : null,
        "CURRENT_BED_NO" : 3376,
        "CURRENT_LOCATION" : "Cluster S2 \/ Damad General Hospital \/ Damad General Hospital \/ Ground Floor \/ ER  \/ ER-OBS F",
        "CUSTOM_DATA" : "null",
        "DIRECT_ADMISSION" : null,
        "DIRECT_ADMISSION_TYPE" : null,
        "ER_ADMISSION_ID" : null,
        "EXPECTED_DISCHARGE_DATE" : "2022-09-29T21:00:00Z",
        "IS_ACTIVE_ADMISSION" : 0,
        "IS_AMBULANCE_REQUIRED" : null,
        "IS_FROM_ER" : 0,
        "IS_IN_WAITING_LIST" : null,
        "IS_NEW_BORN" : 0,
        "IS_OUT_ON_PASS" : 0,
        "IS_PATIENT_CONSENT_TAKEN" : 1,
        "IS_PATIENT_IN_ICU" : 0,
        "IS_PATIENT_PREGNANT" : null,
        "IS_RELATIVE_AVAILABLE" : 0,
        "IS_RELATIVE_ID_TAKEN" : null,
        "IS_TENTATIVE" : 0,
        "IS_WRISTBAND_PRINTED" : null,
        "LOUNGE_BED_CODE" : null,
        "LOUNGE_BED_LOCATION" : null,
        "LOUNGE_BED_NO" : null,
        "LOUNGE_BED_RESERVATION_ID" : null,
        "MULTIPLE_PREGNANCY_TYPE" : null,
        "MULTIPLE_PREGNANCY_TYPE_ID" : null,
        "NATIONALITY" : null,
        "NATIONALITY_ID" : null,
        "NO_OF_WEEKS_PREGNANT" : null,
        "NURSING_GROUP_ID" : 3,
        "NURSING_GROUP_NAME" : "قسم تنويم النساء",
        "PATIENT_GENDER" : 2,
        "PATIENT_ID" : 533325,
        "PATIENT_ID_OF_MOTHER" : null,
        "PATIENT_NAME" : "namisah ali MUSAAD aljawhariu",
        "PATIENT_POMR_ID" : 1791742,
        "PAY_TYPE" : null,
        "PREGNANCY_TYPE" : null,
        "PREGNANCY_TYPE_ID" : null,
        "REFERRAL_DOCTOR_ID" : 7245,
        "REFERRAL_DOCTOR_NAME" : "وليد نقر",
        "REFERRING_CLINIC_ID" : 35376,
        "RELATIVE_ID_NUMBER" : null,
        "REMARKS" : null,
        "ROOM_TYPE_ID" : 104,
        "ROOM_TYPE_NAME" : "Normal Room",
        "TENTATIVE_ROOM_ID" : null,
        "TENTATIVE_ROOM_NAME" : null,
        "DISCHARGE_ID" : 1633548,
        "ROOM_CATEGORY_ID" : 104,
        "ROOM_ID" : 833,
        "ADMITTING_DIAGNOSIS" : "H26.4 After-cataract",
        "FORENSIC_COMMITTEE_APPROVAL_STATUS" : null
    },
    "def": {
        "ADMISSION_ID" : 1632790,
        "ADDITIONAL_DATA" : null,
        "CREATED_BY" : "7348500",
        "CREATED_DATE" : "2022-09-29T02:38:04Z",
        "HOSPITAL" : 105,
        "HOSPITAL_GROUP_ID" : 58,
        "HOSPITAL_ID" : 105,
        "IS_ACTIVE" : null,
        "IS_DELETED" : 0,
        "LOCATION" : null,
        "MODIFIED_BY" : "3615065",
        "MODIFIED_DATE" : "2022-09-29T03:14:04Z",
        "ROW_VERSION" : 2,
        "TENANT_ID" : 58,
        "ADMISSION_NUMBER" : "A20229291626748",
        "ADMISSION_REASON" : null,
        "ADMISSION_REQUEST_NO" : 1649556,
        "ADMISSION_STATUS" : "DISCHARGED",
        "ADMISSION_TYPE" : null,
        "ADMITTED_BY_USER_ID" : null,
        "ADMITTED_BY_USER_NAME" : null,
        "ADMITTED_DATE" : "2022-09-29T02:38:03Z",
        "ADMITTING_DOCTOR_ID" : null,
        "ADMITTING_DOCTOR_NAME" : null,
        "APPOINTMENT_ID" : null,
        "AUTOMATIC_CONSENT_TAKEN" : null,
        "BED_CODE" : null,
        "BED_LOCATION" : null,
        "BED_NO" : null,
        "BED_RESERVATION_ID" : null,
        "CLINIC_GROUP_ID" : null,
        "CLINIC_ID" : 35357,
        "CLINIC_NAME" : "Emergency Department",
        "COMPANION_ID" : null,
        "COMPANION_NAME" : null,
        "COMPANY_APPROVAL_NO" : null,
        "CURRENT_BED_NO" : null,
        "CURRENT_LOCATION" : null,
        "CUSTOM_DATA" : "null",
        "DIRECT_ADMISSION" : null,
        "DIRECT_ADMISSION_TYPE" : null,
        "ER_ADMISSION_ID" : null,
        "EXPECTED_DISCHARGE_DATE" : null,
        "IS_ACTIVE_ADMISSION" : 0,
        "IS_AMBULANCE_REQUIRED" : null,
        "IS_FROM_ER" : 1,
        "IS_IN_WAITING_LIST" : 0,
        "IS_NEW_BORN" : null,
        "IS_OUT_ON_PASS" : null,
        "IS_PATIENT_CONSENT_TAKEN" : null,
        "IS_PATIENT_IN_ICU" : null,
        "IS_PATIENT_PREGNANT" : 0,
        "IS_RELATIVE_AVAILABLE" : null,
        "IS_RELATIVE_ID_TAKEN" : null,
        "IS_TENTATIVE" : null,
        "IS_WRISTBAND_PRINTED" : null,
        "LOUNGE_BED_CODE" : null,
        "LOUNGE_BED_LOCATION" : null,
        "LOUNGE_BED_NO" : null,
        "LOUNGE_BED_RESERVATION_ID" : null,
        "MULTIPLE_PREGNANCY_TYPE" : null,
        "MULTIPLE_PREGNANCY_TYPE_ID" : null,
        "NATIONALITY" : null,
        "NATIONALITY_ID" : null,
        "NO_OF_WEEKS_PREGNANT" : null,
        "NURSING_GROUP_ID" : 1,
        "NURSING_GROUP_NAME" : "EMERGENCY CLINIC GROUP",
        "PATIENT_GENDER" : null,
        "PATIENT_ID" : 533325,
        "PATIENT_ID_OF_MOTHER" : null,
        "PATIENT_NAME" : "namisah ali MUSAAD aljawhariu",
        "PATIENT_POMR_ID" : 2137407,
        "PAY_TYPE" : null,
        "PREGNANCY_TYPE" : null,
        "PREGNANCY_TYPE_ID" : null,
        "REFERRAL_DOCTOR_ID" : null,
        "REFERRAL_DOCTOR_NAME" : null,
        "REFERRING_CLINIC_ID" : null,
        "RELATIVE_ID_NUMBER" : null,
        "REMARKS" : null,
        "ROOM_TYPE_ID" : null,
        "ROOM_TYPE_NAME" : null,
        "TENTATIVE_ROOM_ID" : null,
        "TENTATIVE_ROOM_NAME" : null,
        "DISCHARGE_ID" : 1621865,
        "ROOM_CATEGORY_ID" : null,
        "ROOM_ID" : null,
        "ADMITTING_DIAGNOSIS" : null,
        "FORENSIC_COMMITTEE_APPROVAL_STATUS" : null
    },
    "ijk":{
        "ADMISSION_ID" : 1619783,
        "ADDITIONAL_DATA" : null,
        "CREATED_BY" : "7346831",
        "CREATED_DATE" : "2022-09-25T02:45:04Z",
        "HOSPITAL" : 105,
        "HOSPITAL_GROUP_ID" : 58,
        "HOSPITAL_ID" : 105,
        "IS_ACTIVE" : null,
        "IS_DELETED" : 0,
        "LOCATION" : null,
        "MODIFIED_BY" : "1",
        "MODIFIED_DATE" : "2022-09-25T07:10:13Z",
        "ROW_VERSION" : 4,
        "TENANT_ID" : 58,
        "ADMISSION_NUMBER" : "A20229251613739",
        "ADMISSION_REASON" : "NON_SURGICAL",
        "ADMISSION_REQUEST_NO" : 1636387,
        "ADMISSION_STATUS" : "DISCHARGED",
        "ADMISSION_TYPE" : "Routine",
        "ADMITTED_BY_USER_ID" : null,
        "ADMITTED_BY_USER_NAME" : "Soltan Ahmed Sholn",
        "ADMITTED_DATE" : "2022-09-25T02:45:04Z",
        "ADMITTING_DOCTOR_ID" : 7245,
        "ADMITTING_DOCTOR_NAME" : "وليد نقر",
        "APPOINTMENT_ID" : null,
        "AUTOMATIC_CONSENT_TAKEN" : 0,
        "BED_CODE" : "NICU-8",
        "BED_LOCATION" : "Cluster S2 \/ Damad General Hospital \/ Damad General Hospital \/ Ground Floor \/ NICU \/ NICU-8",
        "BED_NO" : 3366,
        "BED_RESERVATION_ID" : 1015055,
        "CLINIC_GROUP_ID" : null,
        "CLINIC_ID" : 35376,
        "CLINIC_NAME" : "تخصص العيون فرز",
        "COMPANION_ID" : null,
        "COMPANION_NAME" : null,
        "COMPANY_APPROVAL_NO" : null,
        "CURRENT_BED_NO" : 3366,
        "CURRENT_LOCATION" : "Cluster S2 \/ Damad General Hospital \/ Damad General Hospital \/ Ground Floor \/ NICU \/ NICU-8",
        "CUSTOM_DATA" : "null",
        "DIRECT_ADMISSION" : null,
        "DIRECT_ADMISSION_TYPE" : null,
        "ER_ADMISSION_ID" : null,
        "EXPECTED_DISCHARGE_DATE" : "2022-09-25T21:00:00Z",
        "IS_ACTIVE_ADMISSION" : 0,
        "IS_AMBULANCE_REQUIRED" : null,
        "IS_FROM_ER" : 0,
        "IS_IN_WAITING_LIST" : null,
        "IS_NEW_BORN" : 0,
        "IS_OUT_ON_PASS" : 0,
        "IS_PATIENT_CONSENT_TAKEN" : 1,
        "IS_PATIENT_IN_ICU" : 0,
        "IS_PATIENT_PREGNANT" : null,
        "IS_RELATIVE_AVAILABLE" : 0,
        "IS_RELATIVE_ID_TAKEN" : null,
        "IS_TENTATIVE" : 0,
        "IS_WRISTBAND_PRINTED" : null,
        "LOUNGE_BED_CODE" : null,
        "LOUNGE_BED_LOCATION" : null,
        "LOUNGE_BED_NO" : null,
        "LOUNGE_BED_RESERVATION_ID" : null,
        "MULTIPLE_PREGNANCY_TYPE" : null,
        "MULTIPLE_PREGNANCY_TYPE_ID" : null,
        "NATIONALITY" : null,
        "NATIONALITY_ID" : null,
        "NO_OF_WEEKS_PREGNANT" : null,
        "NURSING_GROUP_ID" : 3,
        "NURSING_GROUP_NAME" : "قسم تنويم النساء",
        "PATIENT_GENDER" : 2,
        "PATIENT_ID" : 533325,
        "PATIENT_ID_OF_MOTHER" : null,
        "PATIENT_NAME" : "namisah ali MUSAAD aljawhariu",
        "PATIENT_POMR_ID" : 1791742,
        "PAY_TYPE" : null,
        "PREGNANCY_TYPE" : null,
        "PREGNANCY_TYPE_ID" : null,
        "REFERRAL_DOCTOR_ID" : 7245,
        "REFERRAL_DOCTOR_NAME" : "وليد نقر",
        "REFERRING_CLINIC_ID" : 35376,
        "RELATIVE_ID_NUMBER" : null,
        "REMARKS" : null,
        "ROOM_TYPE_ID" : 103,
        "ROOM_TYPE_NAME" : "DEFAULT",
        "TENTATIVE_ROOM_ID" : null,
        "TENTATIVE_ROOM_NAME" : null,
        "DISCHARGE_ID" : 1609313,
        "ROOM_CATEGORY_ID" : 103,
        "ROOM_ID" : 832,
        "ADMITTING_DIAGNOSIS" : "H25.0 Senile incipient cataract",
        "FORENSIC_COMMITTEE_APPROVAL_STATUS" : null
    },
    "lmn":{
        "ADMISSION_ID" : 1319034,
        "ADDITIONAL_DATA" : null,
        "CREATED_BY" : "150443",
        "CREATED_DATE" : "2022-06-26T13:26:16Z",
        "HOSPITAL" : 101,
        "HOSPITAL_GROUP_ID" : 58,
        "HOSPITAL_ID" : 101,
        "IS_ACTIVE" : null,
        "IS_DELETED" : 0,
        "LOCATION" : null,
        "MODIFIED_BY" : null,
        "MODIFIED_DATE" : "2022-06-26T14:12:37Z",
        "ROW_VERSION" : 3,
        "TENANT_ID" : 58,
        "ADMISSION_NUMBER" : "A20226261312352",
        "ADMISSION_REASON" : null,
        "ADMISSION_REQUEST_NO" : 1334137,
        "ADMISSION_STATUS" : "DISCHARGED",
        "ADMISSION_TYPE" : null,
        "ADMITTED_BY_USER_ID" : null,
        "ADMITTED_BY_USER_NAME" : null,
        "ADMITTED_DATE" : "2022-06-26T13:26:15Z",
        "ADMITTING_DOCTOR_ID" : 5234,
        "ADMITTING_DOCTOR_NAME" : "ALI  JIBRIN",
        "APPOINTMENT_ID" : null,
        "AUTOMATIC_CONSENT_TAKEN" : null,
        "BED_CODE" : null,
        "BED_LOCATION" : null,
        "BED_NO" : null,
        "BED_RESERVATION_ID" : null,
        "CLINIC_GROUP_ID" : null,
        "CLINIC_ID" : 35357,
        "CLINIC_NAME" : "Emergency Department",
        "COMPANION_ID" : null,
        "COMPANION_NAME" : null,
        "COMPANY_APPROVAL_NO" : null,
        "CURRENT_BED_NO" : null,
        "CURRENT_LOCATION" : null,
        "CUSTOM_DATA" : "null",
        "DIRECT_ADMISSION" : null,
        "DIRECT_ADMISSION_TYPE" : null,
        "ER_ADMISSION_ID" : null,
        "EXPECTED_DISCHARGE_DATE" : null,
        "IS_ACTIVE_ADMISSION" : 0,
        "IS_AMBULANCE_REQUIRED" : null,
        "IS_FROM_ER" : 1,
        "IS_IN_WAITING_LIST" : 0,
        "IS_NEW_BORN" : null,
        "IS_OUT_ON_PASS" : null,
        "IS_PATIENT_CONSENT_TAKEN" : null,
        "IS_PATIENT_IN_ICU" : null,
        "IS_PATIENT_PREGNANT" : 0,
        "IS_RELATIVE_AVAILABLE" : null,
        "IS_RELATIVE_ID_TAKEN" : null,
        "IS_TENTATIVE" : null,
        "IS_WRISTBAND_PRINTED" : null,
        "LOUNGE_BED_CODE" : null,
        "LOUNGE_BED_LOCATION" : null,
        "LOUNGE_BED_NO" : null,
        "LOUNGE_BED_RESERVATION_ID" : null,
        "MULTIPLE_PREGNANCY_TYPE" : null,
        "MULTIPLE_PREGNANCY_TYPE_ID" : null,
        "NATIONALITY" : null,
        "NATIONALITY_ID" : null,
        "NO_OF_WEEKS_PREGNANT" : null,
        "NURSING_GROUP_ID" : 1,
        "NURSING_GROUP_NAME" : "EMERGENCY CLINIC GROUP",
        "PATIENT_GENDER" : null,
        "PATIENT_ID" : 533325,
        "PATIENT_ID_OF_MOTHER" : null,
        "PATIENT_NAME" : "namisah ali MUSAAD aljawhariu",
        "PATIENT_POMR_ID" : 1710194,
        "PAY_TYPE" : null,
        "PREGNANCY_TYPE" : null,
        "PREGNANCY_TYPE_ID" : null,
        "REFERRAL_DOCTOR_ID" : null,
        "REFERRAL_DOCTOR_NAME" : null,
        "REFERRING_CLINIC_ID" : null,
        "RELATIVE_ID_NUMBER" : null,
        "REMARKS" : null,
        "ROOM_TYPE_ID" : null,
        "ROOM_TYPE_NAME" : null,
        "TENTATIVE_ROOM_ID" : null,
        "TENTATIVE_ROOM_NAME" : null,
        "DISCHARGE_ID" : 1295097,
        "ROOM_CATEGORY_ID" : null,
        "ROOM_ID" : null,
        "ADMITTING_DIAGNOSIS" : null,
        "FORENSIC_COMMITTEE_APPROVAL_STATUS" : null
    },
    "opq":{
        "ADMISSION_ID" : 677215,
        "ADDITIONAL_DATA" : null,
        "CREATED_BY" : "1069144143",
        "CREATED_DATE" : "2021-12-11T15:50:26Z",
        "HOSPITAL" : 101,
        "HOSPITAL_GROUP_ID" : 58,
        "HOSPITAL_ID" : 101,
        "IS_ACTIVE" : null,
        "IS_DELETED" : 0,
        "LOCATION" : null,
        "MODIFIED_BY" : null,
        "MODIFIED_DATE" : "2022-01-04T11:32:59Z",
        "ROW_VERSION" : 3,
        "TENANT_ID" : 58,
        "ADMISSION_NUMBER" : "A20211211670311",
        "ADMISSION_REASON" : null,
        "ADMISSION_REQUEST_NO" : 681889,
        "ADMISSION_STATUS" : "DISCHARGED",
        "ADMISSION_TYPE" : null,
        "ADMITTED_BY_USER_ID" : null,
        "ADMITTED_BY_USER_NAME" : null,
        "ADMITTED_DATE" : "2021-12-11T15:50:26Z",
        "ADMITTING_DOCTOR_ID" : 5229,
        "ADMITTING_DOCTOR_NAME" : "AMAL  ALI",
        "APPOINTMENT_ID" : null,
        "AUTOMATIC_CONSENT_TAKEN" : null,
        "BED_CODE" : null,
        "BED_LOCATION" : null,
        "BED_NO" : null,
        "BED_RESERVATION_ID" : null,
        "CLINIC_GROUP_ID" : null,
        "CLINIC_ID" : 35357,
        "CLINIC_NAME" : "Emergency Department",
        "COMPANION_ID" : null,
        "COMPANION_NAME" : null,
        "COMPANY_APPROVAL_NO" : null,
        "CURRENT_BED_NO" : null,
        "CURRENT_LOCATION" : null,
        "CUSTOM_DATA" : "null",
        "DIRECT_ADMISSION" : null,
        "DIRECT_ADMISSION_TYPE" : null,
        "ER_ADMISSION_ID" : null,
        "EXPECTED_DISCHARGE_DATE" : null,
        "IS_ACTIVE_ADMISSION" : 0,
        "IS_AMBULANCE_REQUIRED" : null,
        "IS_FROM_ER" : 1,
        "IS_IN_WAITING_LIST" : 0,
        "IS_NEW_BORN" : null,
        "IS_OUT_ON_PASS" : null,
        "IS_PATIENT_CONSENT_TAKEN" : null,
        "IS_PATIENT_IN_ICU" : null,
        "IS_PATIENT_PREGNANT" : 0,
        "IS_RELATIVE_AVAILABLE" : null,
        "IS_RELATIVE_ID_TAKEN" : null,
        "IS_TENTATIVE" : null,
        "IS_WRISTBAND_PRINTED" : null,
        "LOUNGE_BED_CODE" : null,
        "LOUNGE_BED_LOCATION" : null,
        "LOUNGE_BED_NO" : null,
        "LOUNGE_BED_RESERVATION_ID" : null,
        "MULTIPLE_PREGNANCY_TYPE" : null,
        "MULTIPLE_PREGNANCY_TYPE_ID" : null,
        "NATIONALITY" : null,
        "NATIONALITY_ID" : null,
        "NO_OF_WEEKS_PREGNANT" : null,
        "NURSING_GROUP_ID" : 1,
        "NURSING_GROUP_NAME" : "EMERGENCY CLINIC GROUP",
        "PATIENT_GENDER" : null,
        "PATIENT_ID" : 533325,
        "PATIENT_ID_OF_MOTHER" : null,
        "PATIENT_NAME" : "namisah ali MUSAAD aljawhariu",
        "PATIENT_POMR_ID" : 846859,
        "PAY_TYPE" : null,
        "PREGNANCY_TYPE" : null,
        "PREGNANCY_TYPE_ID" : null,
        "REFERRAL_DOCTOR_ID" : null,
        "REFERRAL_DOCTOR_NAME" : null,
        "REFERRING_CLINIC_ID" : null,
        "RELATIVE_ID_NUMBER" : null,
        "REMARKS" : null,
        "ROOM_TYPE_ID" : null,
        "ROOM_TYPE_NAME" : null,
        "TENTATIVE_ROOM_ID" : null,
        "TENTATIVE_ROOM_NAME" : null,
        "DISCHARGE_ID" : 712310,
        "ROOM_CATEGORY_ID" : null,
        "ROOM_ID" : null,
        "ADMITTING_DIAGNOSIS" : null,
        "FORENSIC_COMMITTEE_APPROVAL_STATUS" : null
    },
    "rst":{
        "ADMISSION_ID" : 677040,
        "ADDITIONAL_DATA" : null,
        "CREATED_BY" : "7333953",
        "CREATED_DATE" : "2021-12-11T14:52:53Z",
        "HOSPITAL" : 105,
        "HOSPITAL_GROUP_ID" : 58,
        "HOSPITAL_ID" : 105,
        "IS_ACTIVE" : null,
        "IS_DELETED" : 0,
        "LOCATION" : null,
        "MODIFIED_BY" : null,
        "MODIFIED_DATE" : "2021-12-13T23:43:08Z",
        "ROW_VERSION" : 2,
        "TENANT_ID" : 58,
        "ADMISSION_NUMBER" : "A20211211670136",
        "ADMISSION_REASON" : null,
        "ADMISSION_REQUEST_NO" : 681686,
        "ADMISSION_STATUS" : "DISCHARGED",
        "ADMISSION_TYPE" : null,
        "ADMITTED_BY_USER_ID" : null,
        "ADMITTED_BY_USER_NAME" : null,
        "ADMITTED_DATE" : "2021-12-11T14:52:53Z",
        "ADMITTING_DOCTOR_ID" : null,
        "ADMITTING_DOCTOR_NAME" : null,
        "APPOINTMENT_ID" : null,
        "AUTOMATIC_CONSENT_TAKEN" : null,
        "BED_CODE" : null,
        "BED_LOCATION" : null,
        "BED_NO" : null,
        "BED_RESERVATION_ID" : null,
        "CLINIC_GROUP_ID" : null,
        "CLINIC_ID" : 35357,
        "CLINIC_NAME" : "Emergency Department",
        "COMPANION_ID" : null,
        "COMPANION_NAME" : null,
        "COMPANY_APPROVAL_NO" : null,
        "CURRENT_BED_NO" : null,
        "CURRENT_LOCATION" : null,
        "CUSTOM_DATA" : "null",
        "DIRECT_ADMISSION" : null,
        "DIRECT_ADMISSION_TYPE" : null,
        "ER_ADMISSION_ID" : null,
        "EXPECTED_DISCHARGE_DATE" : null,
        "IS_ACTIVE_ADMISSION" : 0,
        "IS_AMBULANCE_REQUIRED" : null,
        "IS_FROM_ER" : 1,
        "IS_IN_WAITING_LIST" : 0,
        "IS_NEW_BORN" : null,
        "IS_OUT_ON_PASS" : null,
        "IS_PATIENT_CONSENT_TAKEN" : null,
        "IS_PATIENT_IN_ICU" : null,
        "IS_PATIENT_PREGNANT" : 0,
        "IS_RELATIVE_AVAILABLE" : null,
        "IS_RELATIVE_ID_TAKEN" : null,
        "IS_TENTATIVE" : null,
        "IS_WRISTBAND_PRINTED" : null,
        "LOUNGE_BED_CODE" : null,
        "LOUNGE_BED_LOCATION" : null,
        "LOUNGE_BED_NO" : null,
        "LOUNGE_BED_RESERVATION_ID" : null,
        "MULTIPLE_PREGNANCY_TYPE" : null,
        "MULTIPLE_PREGNANCY_TYPE_ID" : null,
        "NATIONALITY" : null,
        "NATIONALITY_ID" : null,
        "NO_OF_WEEKS_PREGNANT" : null,
        "NURSING_GROUP_ID" : 1,
        "NURSING_GROUP_NAME" : "EMERGENCY CLINIC GROUP",
        "PATIENT_GENDER" : null,
        "PATIENT_ID" : 533325,
        "PATIENT_ID_OF_MOTHER" : null,
        "PATIENT_NAME" : "namisah ali MUSAAD aljawhariu",
        "PATIENT_POMR_ID" : 846666,
        "PAY_TYPE" : null,
        "PREGNANCY_TYPE" : null,
        "PREGNANCY_TYPE_ID" : null,
        "REFERRAL_DOCTOR_ID" : null,
        "REFERRAL_DOCTOR_NAME" : null,
        "REFERRING_CLINIC_ID" : null,
        "RELATIVE_ID_NUMBER" : null,
        "REMARKS" : null,
        "ROOM_TYPE_ID" : null,
        "ROOM_TYPE_NAME" : null,
        "TENTATIVE_ROOM_ID" : null,
        "TENTATIVE_ROOM_NAME" : null,
        "DISCHARGE_ID" : 652379,
        "ROOM_CATEGORY_ID" : null,
        "ROOM_ID" : null,
        "ADMITTING_DIAGNOSIS" : null,
        "FORENSIC_COMMITTEE_APPROVAL_STATUS" : null
    }}

console.log(demoObject);
```

Answer (score -3):

Look at **Proxy** is not an array :
**example :** In this example I have an object inside of this object I have multiples objects each object has a key.

```js
const proxy = {
  obj_1: {id: 1},
  obj_2: {id: 2}
  obj_3: {id: 3}
  obj_4: {id: 4}
  obj_5: {id: 5}
}
```

But in the first One you've an array inside of this array we have multiple objects there is a difference, the object is not iterator you can't looping over objects, but array is iterator.

**example :**

```js
// array store multiple objects
const array = [{...},{...},{...},{...},{...}];
```